# ASP.NET MVC timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a request that is happening in our frontend ASP.NET MVC application that hits another service.

Our front end application makes the call to the external service then it times out.

We hit the service with Postman and we are able to get a response, albeit a slow one, roughly ranging from 1:42 to 2 minutes (we are working on speeding it up but we can't do that part at the moment without a lot of time we don't have a the moment).

That said, our frontend application doing the call is throwing an internal server error right about 1:30 - 1:40 because there is not a response happening within that time.

I have in the we have the "executionTimeout" set to 300 seconds. Which should be plenty of time

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" 
             enableVersionHeader="false" executionTimeout="300" />
```

That said, we are still getting a timeout on the request. Is there any other timeout or property we should be looking at to allow the frontend application time to wait for the response?

The client is posting the call through the controller to out external service through a form post in which it does a JSONClientSend then waits for a response of the result.

Some code:

```
private PostOrderCommunicationsModel GetMessageTemplate(PostOrderCommunicationsModel model)
{
    var toEmails = model?.OrderMessageBlocks?.ToEmail;
    ModelState.Clear();

    var selectedTemplateId = model.SelectedTemplateId;

    if (model.OrderId == 0 || model.SelectedTemplateId == 0) 
        return model;

    model = GetOrderStatus(model);
    model.SelectedTemplateId = selectedTemplateId;

    var msgTemplate = OurServiceCalls.GetOurPostOrderCommunicationsMessageByOrderIdAndTemplateId(model.OrderId, selectedTemplateId);

    model.OrderMessageBlocks = msgTemplate;
    model.OrderMessageBlocks.ToEmail = toEmails ?? model.OrderMessageBlocks.ToEmail;

    return model;
}
```

Then calls to:

```
public static cPostOrderCommunicationsMessage GetOurPostOrderCommunicationsMessageByOrderIdAndTemplateId(int orderId, int templateId)
{
    var jsonClient = ourService;
    var pocMsg = new CommunicationsGetOurPostOrderCommunicationMessageByOrderIdAndTemplateId
        {
            UniqueId = _UniqueId,
            OrderId = orderId,
            TemplateId = templateId
        };

    var results = jsonClient.Send(pocMsg);

    return results;
}
```

Comment: If the timeout error is originating from the client then log the response on the client (in the browser you can use the development tools) and post that in your question. Include how you are making the request from the client (include the relevant code).

Comment: The client is posting the call through the controller to out external service through a form post in which it does a JSONClientSend then waits for a response of the result.

Comment: Increasing the timeout on the server isn't going to fix a timeout that's happening on the client side.  You haven't actually shown on the client side the code that's making the API call, or what that timeout is set to.